# scp command can't copy empty file

Tags: scp

i am trying to copy empty file with scp, this file is copied in remote server (Windows + SolarWinds SCP/SFTP server). No problem with non empty file.

However, i have this log:

```
Sending file modes: C0644 0 TEST_1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to myserver closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 1712, received 1392 bytes, in 122.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 14.0, received 11.4
debug1: Exit status -1
lost connection
```

or i can't have a return from command and i am forced to kill it.

```
Sending file modes: C0644 0 TEST_1
^C 
[user@server ~]$ debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 1.
```

So, the return code is 1 and my script returns a error code.

Comment: Offhand, in those debug traces it looks like the problem is on the remote server.

Comment: But why i can copy a non empty file?